# Kendo grid's InCell editing doesnt work with jQuery 3.1.1

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik's UI for ASP.NET. I have configured my grid for `InCell` editing by following the article [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom)

Here is my code

**Index.cshtml**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyGridVM>()
    .Name("myGrid")
    .Columns(col =>
    {                        
        col.Bound(o => o.TaxYear).Title("Tax Year").Width(64);
        col.Bound(o => o.Deadline).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Title("Deadline").Width(110);            
    })         
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))        
    .AutoBind(false)                              
    .Scrollable(s => s.Height("Auto"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource            
        .Model(model =>
        {

            model.Field(o => o.Deadline);                
            model.Field(o => o.TaxYear).Editable(false);                
        })            
        .Read(read => read
                .Action("GetData", "Home"))
        .ServerOperation(false))
)
```

**I have EditorTemplate for Deadline.

DeadlineEditor.cshtml**

```
@model MyGridVM

@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name("Deadline")
    .Value("Deadline")
    .Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")
)
```

**MyGridVm.cs** I used UIHint for deadline property

```
public class MyGridVM
{        
        public short? TaxYear { get; set; }

        [UIHint("DeadlineEditor")]
        public DateTime? Deadline { get; set; }     

}
```

With this configuration everything was working fine with `UI for ASP.NET version 2015.2.902` and `jQuery version 1.11.2`

Recently i have updated `UI for ASP.NET version to 2016.3.1118` and made sure Incell editing is working correctly.

Today, I have also updated jQuery version from `1.11.2` to `3.1.1`. With jQuery update now have to double click on the cell to edit it. Previously it was just single click to edit the grid cell. ( As show in [demo here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom) )

As per the Telerik's [documentation here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites) version 2016.3.1118 is compatible with jQuery 3.1.1
[image]

How do i fix this issue without rolling back jQuery. I want single click to edit the cell instead of double click.

Comment: Might be easiest to just use 1.12.3 if single click is necessary and 3.1.1 doesn't have specific features you need? :( Good luck LP13!

Comment: Since we have already updated Kendo we will be testing all the functionalities. So i thought of upgrading jQuery now so we don't have to test all the functionalities again if we update it latter

Comment: Maybe double click to edit isn't a deal breaker? I'd suggest you take this up on Telerik's support forum, their support folks might have some more in-depth info on why it's changed from single click to double click? :( Sorry I can't be of more help!